# Combine multiple backgrounds on android XML?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

Can I combine my own android drawable and ?android:selectableItemBackground...?
I searched a lot but I can't find the right answer...
For example lets say I have a simple button and I want this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" | @drawable/myDrawable/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

How about using FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/myDrawable">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

or using ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bTest"
    android:src="@drawable/myDrawable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Comment: I have like this bro, I was wondering if it is achievable with less code..

Comment: OK, then you can define a combined drawable by using layer-list.